# splitting words by syllable with CMU Pronunciation Dictionary, NLTK, and Python3

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I am working on a natural language processing project and am stuck on splitting words into syllables (using `nltk` and `cmudict.dict()` in `python 3`).

I currently count syllables by looking a word in my corpus up in the CMU Pronunciation Dictionary and counting the number of stresses in its list of phonemes. This appears to work pretty well.

What I am stuck on is how to use this information to split the accompanying grapheme after counting, as I do not understand how to either translate the phonemes back to the graphemes (seems error prone) or use the list of phonemes to somehow split the grapheme.

Here is the function I wrote to do this (word tokenization happens elsewhere):

```
def getSyllables(self):
    pronunciation = cmudict.dict() # get the pronunciation dictionary
    syllableThreshold = 1 # we dont care about 1 syllable words right now
    for word in self.tokens:
        for grapheme, phonemes in pronunciation.items():
            if grapheme == word.lower(): # all graphemes are lowercase, we have to word.lower() to match
                syllableCounter = 0
                for x in phonemes[0]:
                    for y in x:
                        if y[-1].isdigit(): # an item ending in a number is a stress (syllable)
                            syllableCounter += 1
                if syllableCounter > syllableThreshold:
                    output = ' '.join([word, "=", str(syllableCounter)])
                    print(output)
                    print(phonemes)
                else:
                    print(word)
```

Just as an example, my current output is:

```
Once
an
angry = 2
[['AE1', 'NG', 'G', 'R', 'IY0']]
man
```

How can I split the word `angry`, for example, into `an - gry`?

Comment: Are you sure you are not looking for a *hyphenation* algorithm instead? English hyphenation does not always follow pronounciation rules. (If the answer is "well actually yeah", a standard algo to look for is Knuth-Liang's, which delivers good enough results for TeX.)

Comment: oh interesting, didn't even know hyphenation was a thing. this looks like what i want, i will give it a shot, thanks!

Comment: Find yourself a copy of Knuth's hyphenation patterns (remove the TeX stuff) and the rules, and have a go at it yourself. It's perfectly do-able – although I bet there are pre-made libraries as well.